# Asp.net site diplays differently on coworkers computer

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer

I have an asp.net site that displays the way I want it to on my computer in IE8 and firefox.  On my co-worker's computer the page content gets pushed down below the left side menu.

We both have the exact same version of IE8.

I'm using divs and css for positioning and a Masterpage.

```
body
{
    background-position: center center;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: medium;
    background-color: #000000;

}

* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

#dateField{}

#head
{
    color: #00FF00;
}

#topContent
{
    background-position: url(Images/bg2.gif) repeat-x;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(Images/bg2.gif) repeat-x;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: x-large;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 87px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 87px;
}

#topContent span {vertical-align:middle}



 #leftContent
{

    background-position: #0094D6 url(Images/contentbg.gif) repeat-x;
    width: 170px; /*background: #0094D6 url(Images/contentbg.gif) repeat-x;*/
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: left;
    position: static;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    left: 0px;
    float: left;
    height: 574px;
}
#SideTableFiller
{
    height: 262px;
    background-color: #000000;
}



#mainContent
{
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 190px;
    padding: 2px;
    color: #FFFFFF;


}

#footerContent
{
    background: url(Images/footer.jpg) repeat-x;
    height: 100px;


    clear: left;

}
```

Comment: The situation what you are in is called "CROSS BROWSER COMPATIBILITY".Google it or use the search@Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Aseem Gautam No, if you read it he says, they are BOTH using the SAME version of IE, therfore making it NOT cross browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running it from "localhost" and s/he is running it as a site on the "intRAnet".

In IE8, intRAnets are rendered in NON-IE8 Standards mode by DEFAULT, but Localhost and IntERnet sites are run in IE8 Standards mode by DEFAULT.

Paste this into your/their addressbar to see what mode you are actually in:

```
javascript:var%20vMode=document.documentMode;var%20rMode='IE5%20Quirks%20Mode';if(vMode==8){rMode='IE8%20Standards%20Mode';}else%20if(vMode==7){rMode='IE7%20Strict%20Mode';}alert('Rendering%20in:%20'+rMode);
```

You'll get 1 of 3 values: [IE5 Quirks Mode | IE7 Strict Mode | IE8 Standards Mode]

*and of course each renders slightly different... and JavaScript behaves differently ;-)*

Comment: you can use the developer console (f12 key) to see what mode the browser is in while viewing the page, if you think this is the case.

Comment: yes it's running on my pc

both computers say "Rendering in IE8 Standards Mode"

Comment: It was the intranet compatibiltiy mode setting.  Thanks for everyones help

Answer (score 4):

Does one of you have the compatibility button pressed in IE?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `float: left` in your CSS, I assume that the page contents (sidemenu + mainContent) do not fit next to each other in your coworker's browser window, and are therefore pushed below the sidemenu.

Maybe your coworker is using a different screen resolution, or he has a zoom level greater than 100% in IE.

Comment: when I zoom in on my comuter it doesn't push the contents down..it just adds a scroll bar at the bottom of the screen to you can see what is to the right of the edge of the screen

Answer (score 0):

isnt your IE8 compability mode enabled? try disabling it;

if the users visited your site before, they may be with browser cache, try Ctrl+F5 on their browser with your site open to refresh cache

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the other person may have a different zoom level applied.

Answer (score 0):

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">` 
as the first line on the page should force IE8 Standards Mode regardless of where the page is being viewed.